# Converting list of strings with decimal places to ints in python

Tags: python, string, int

```
example_list = ['21.48678', '21.46552', '21.45145', '21.43822',
                '21.42734', '21.41222', '21.40132', '21.37679']
```

Im having a bit of trouble converting this list from strings to integers,  I would like to also have it as whole numbers.  Thanks :)

Comment: How would you like them rounded?

Answer (score 7):

Simplest thing is

```
[int(float(x)) for x in your_list]
```

This will truncate all the numbers

If you want to round the numbers use this instead

```
[int(float(x)+.5) for x in your_list]
```

Comment: how would you do it if you wanted decimal places as well

Comment: @bluelantern, not sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: @bluelantern, sure just use `[float(x) for x in your_list]`. They can't be ints then of course

Answer (score 3):

At first convert to `float`

```
>>> lst = ['21.48678', '21.46552', '21.45145', '21.43822', '21.42734', '21.41222', '21.40132', '21.37679']
>>> ints = [int(float(num)) for num in lst]
[21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = ['21.48678', '21.46552', '21.45145', '21.43822', '21.42734', '21.41222', '21.40132', '21.37679']

map(lambda x: int(float(x)), foo)
```

Comment: This will be slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: @gnibbler acutally using `map` [could be faster](http://pastebin.com/2MZJgSze) if done without `lambda` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(round(float(i))) for i in example_list]
```

will convert items in the list to `float`, *round* them and then convert them to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[]
for each in example_list:
    Integer = int(each)
    new_list.append(Integer)
print new_list
```

This is easy for beginner to understand:D